# Entity Relationship Diagram or Class Diagrams

Tags: uml, entity, entity-relationship, class-diagram, erd

How to know when should I use Entity Relationship Diagram or Class Diagrams, and which one of them is easier to learn/use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ER diagrams map more directly to a relational database. UML diagrams can represent a more abstract view that requires interpretation, but represents the same thing, assuming you turn off operations and understand how to flatten generalizations.

ER diagrams may be easier for you to learn.

Answer (score 2):

Both ER diagrams (ERDs) and UML class diagrams can be used for designing a relational database schema. The language of UML Class Diagrams is a superset of ERDs and it has been standardized, while for ERDs, there are different flavors, which may be confusing. For historical and cultural reasons, ERDs are still widely used in the database community. However, if you develop both databases and application code, then there is no good reason to make additional ERDs, when you have to make class diagrams for your application design. It's more economic using the same class diagrams (in conceptual and logical design) both for your database and your Java or C# classes.

Answer (score 0):

The implicit assumption in your question is wrong. ERD and Class diagram are not two ways of doing the same thing. They have completely separate purposes. Answers from @Jim L and @gwag are inaccurate and misleading as they repeat your wrong assumption.

ERD is used when you are designing a **relational database**.
Class Diagram is used when you are designing an **object-oriented application**, e.g. an Android app.

It should be clear by now that a relational database and Android app are of two different categories of thing.

Comment: One can use UML to design relational databases and generate DDL. I've done it many times. It's not hard.

Comment: @Jim L, Do you know what you are talking about? He is asking if class diagram and ERD are the same thing, which obviously not. Down voting before you actually understand something is really a bad thing.

Comment: While I agree that ERD and UML are not the same thing, there is a one to one correspondence of many of the concepts. UML is a superset of the expressivity of ERD. Just because you don't know how to model a database in both languages doesn't make me wrong.

Comment: I suggest you drop the accusatory tone and seek to understand.

Comment: If you want to edit your answer to express a different opinion about why you think UML is inferior for database design and drop the "Answers from Jim L and gwag are inaccurate and misleading" bit, I'll be happy to retract my down-vote.

Comment: While this answer is correct, it isn't very helpful: it doesn't say anything about what problems one would encounter when trying to use a UML class diagram for relational database design, or vice versa, an ERD diagram for an object-oriented class design.